# Find REGEX in every file in a folder

Tags: vb.net

I need to evaluate each file in a folder for the ICN string. Then add each ICN to an output file. I found the code below and have made changes to it to meet my needs but it only adds one found file in the ICN.log instead of looping through all files.

```
    Private Sub btnFindICN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFindICN.Click

    Dim Regex = New Regex("[<][!]ENTITY (ICN.*?)[.]\w+")
    Dim output = New List(Of String)
    Dim tLoc = txtFolderPath.Text
    Dim txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(tLoc, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

    For Each tFile In txtFiles
        Dim input = File.ReadAllText(tFile)

        If Regex.IsMatch(input) Then
            Console.Write("REGEX found in " + tFile)
            output.Add(tFile)
            Exit For
        End If

    Next
    File.WriteAllLines(tLoc.TrimEnd("\"c) & "\ICN.log", output)
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using RegEx at all. It seems like it would be much simpler and probably more efficient to load a XDocument with the content of `input` and then traverse the XDocument for your desired value.

Comment: I've never used XDocument. Could you show me how that code would work?

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle, it is over-simplified but it gives you an idea: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IraLFC

Comment: @David - OP is searching for something in an inline DTD. `XDocument` parses an inline DTD into `DocumentType.InternalSubet` and that's it. It still requires a text search. The only benefit would be that it prevents false positives elsewhere in the document. Is it really worth loading the whole document for that? Only the OP can say.

Comment: Now `XmlDocument`... that's another story. Its `DocumentType` property has an `Entities` collection with each `<!ENTITY...>` declaration parsed and presented with `Name`/`LocalName` and `InnerText` properties. But again, it involves parsing the whole document. Maybe using `XmlReader` directly would be a better choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I removed the for exit for the code works.

```
    Private Sub btnFindICN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFindICN.Click


    Dim Regex = New Regex("[<][!]ENTITY (ICN.*?)[.]\w+")
    Dim output = New List(Of String)
    Dim tLoc = txtFolderPath.Text
    Dim txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(tLoc, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

    For Each tFile In txtFiles
        'MsgBox(tFile)
        Dim input = File.ReadAllText(tFile)

        If Regex.IsMatch(input) Then
            Console.Write("REGEX found in " + tFile)
            output.Add(tFile)
            'Exit For
        End If
    Next
    File.WriteAllLines(tLoc.TrimEnd("\"c) & "\ICN.log", output)
    MsgBox("Function Complete")
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes. The `Exit For` inside your original if-block will break the for-loop when the first match is found. Breaking the loop is useful if you want to search for the first match only. Good catch. :)